# DNAT from localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: iptables, localhost, dnat

I'd like to set up a TCP DNAT from 127.0.0.1, port 4242 to 11.22.33.44, port 5353 on Linux 3.x (currently 3.2.52, but I can upgrade if needed).

It looks like the simple DNAT rule setup doesn't work, `telnet 127.0.0.1 4242` hangs for a minute in `Trying 127.0.0.1...`, and then it times out. Maybe it's because the kernel is discarding the returning packets (e.g. SYN+ACK), because it considers them Martian. I don't need an explanation why the simple solution doesn't work, I need a solution, even if it's complicated (e.g. it involves creating may rules).

I could set up a usual DNAT from another local IP address, outside the `127.0.0.0/8` network, but now I need 127.0.0.1 as the destination address. I know that I can set up a user-level port forwarding process, but now I need a solution which can be set up using `iptables` and doesn't need helper processes.

I was googling for this for an hour. It was asked multiple times, but I couldn't find any working solutions.

Also there are many questions about DNAT to 127.0.0.1, but I don't need that, I need the opposite.

Please note that a single `iptables -j REDIRECT` rule wouldn't work, because I need to change the IP address of the outgoing packet from 127.0.0.1 to 11.22.33.44, and `-j REDIRECT` can't change the IP address.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, routing traffic from `localhost:8081` to `172.17.0.1:80`, where `172.17.0.1` is a veth behind the bridge interface named `docker0`.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.docker0.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o docker0 -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type UNICAST -j MASQUERADE
```

A key piece of the puzzle is the `MASQUERADE` rule.

Further inspiration:

- [How do I forward localhost traffic to a remote host with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/616275/how-do-i-forward-localhost-traffic-to-a-remote-host-with-iptables)
- [iptables DNAT from loopback](https://serverfault.com/questions/363899/iptables-dnat-from-loopback)
- https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/6810

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1` didn't make any difference, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to run the following three commands to make it work:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 4242 -j DNAT --to 11.22.33.44:5353
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 -d 11.22.33.44 --dport 5353 -j SNAT --to $your-eth0-ip
```

Here is the detailed explanation.

The first command will do the DNAT as expected. However, if you try to capture packet with only this rule set, you will find you get nothing:

```
tcpdump -i any -n port 5353
```

This is because linux kernel drop this kind of packet by default, if the packet has `127.0.0.0/8` as one end, and an external ip address as the other end.

The second command changes the kernel parameter, to let this kind of packet pass (of course, you should change `eth0` accordingly). After this, when you capture packet on eth0, you will see packets sent out, but with source address `127.0.0.1` and destination address `11.22.33.44`. Whether this packet can reach the target server or not (the intermediate routers will drop this packet), there is no way for this packet to return. So you should add an `SNAT` rule, to change the source address to your eth0's. And now it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1` didn't make any difference, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you need ? [iptables port redirect not working for localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost)

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Adrien

Comment: Thank you for writing your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, because `-j REDIRECT` can't change the IP address, and I need to change it from 127.0.0.1 to 11.22.33.44. If I didn't need to change the IP address, it would work.

Comment: iptables won't change the IP address. What are you trying to achieve ? Why do you want to change the IP address ?

Comment: Sorry, missed some lines. So, it's not a REDIRECT that you need, but rather something like :
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1 -j DNAT --to 11.22.33.44`

But according to what you're trying to do, if you only change the 127.0.0.1 packet, you'll also need to change the return packet (11.22.33.44 => 127.0.0.1). 
Have a look on [this Schema](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Diagrama_linux_netfilter_iptables.gif) to understand placement of tables :

Comment: @Adrien M.: Yes, this (with `-j DNAT`) is the standard solution, but it doesn't work for `telnet 127.0.0.1 4242` (it works with all other local IP address), because Linux is dropping the response packets (see the details in the question). If you think you have a solution which solves the problem, please post it.

Comment: @Lawrence: I'm trying to achieve that the connection initiated by `telnet 127.0.0.1 4242` gets forwarded to 11.22.33.44:5353 by the kernel, without using a user-level port forwarder process. Sorry if this was not clear from the question.

Comment: Ah Righto then. When you said iptables won't change the IP address I got a bit confused.

Comment: FWIW Adrien's wikimedia link was changed from gif to png, here is the updated: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Diagrama_linux_netfilter_iptables.png